# svn commit problem, Cannot read 'd:\UC\db\txn-current': End of file found

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem commiting to svn server, Here's what I got,

> File Can't read
>   'D:\SVNROOT\UC\db\txn-current'.: End
>   of file found

(It's traslation of Korean, so there's might be differ than what English error said..)

In previously, I shut down transaction when update from svn, cause some file was so big,

so I was shut down downloading for delete big files first, but after that, I got message

about 'txn-current',

does anybody can help me to solve this?

thank you for regarding this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db\txn-current` is a file in the repository data on the server which should contain the current revision number if you open it with a text editor.

If this is not the case (as the error message seems to indicate), then you should first try to run `svnadmin recover D:\SVNROOT\UC\` on the server.

You should also run `svnadmin verify D:\SVNROOT\UC\` to check if there are any other problems with the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a clean work dir and also delete any lock file in .svn dir in work directory

Also, make sure the permissions on the repository directory are proper

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `repository_path/db/current` was blank.

I just write latest revision number in current file and run recovery command.

I.e.,

```
svnadmin recover repository_path
```